# Flutter does not recognize Route and RouteSettings. How to import these classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-dependencies, navigator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF0Kp.png)

```
class RouteGenerator {
static Route<dynamic> getRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
String args = routeSettings.arguments.toString();

switch (routeSettings.name) {
  //signIn and signUp
  case Routes.splashRoute:
    initSplashModule();
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SplashScreen());...
```

I have pulled it from the develop branch and did use flutter pub get and flutter clean and flutter upgrade. Tried restarting IDE. I ran flutter doctor and checked everything was okay.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` should do the trick.

RouteSettings is part of the material package.

Comment: I did import the package...it is still showing the error.